# How to make a gradient background in React with single color?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

I want to make a Gradient Background for a Component in React like shown in the image below

[Gradient of the same colour](https://www.wallpapermaiden.com/wallpaper/22011/download/2560x1600/blue-gradient.png)

I want to do it like: `<Box colour ="blue"></Box>` where the styles for these components will be like

```
backgroundColor="this.props.colour"
```

now I just want to pass the colour prop, I don't want to pass two colours also the colour will be in hex code.

Comment: as far as I'm concerned, the image that you linked is a gradient between 2 colors (from red to orange, roughly speaking)...

Comment: yes, it is a gradient between two colors (orange,light-orange) but I want to make it using single  primary color that is here orange.

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you use the gradient as a layer above the `background-color` to achieve this:

```css
.box{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background:linear-gradient(rgba(250,0,0,0.5),transparent);
  background-color:orange /*this your primary color*/
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You still need to specify the second color *somehow*. You can pass in the first color, and then perhaps calculate the second color in the component. Here I convert the second color to be 20% darker than the input color.

You can adjust the logic as needed for your specific use-case.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Box color1="#FFA500" />
    );
  }
}

const Box = ({color1}) => {
  const rgb = [color1.substring(1,3), color1.substring(3,5), color1.substring(5,7)];
  const color2 = `rgb(${rgb.map(c => (parseInt(c, 16) * 0.8)).join()})`;
  return (
    <div className="box" style={{background: `linear-gradient(${color1}, ${color2})`}} />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```